# How to get the creator screen of an issue with Jira Rest API?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am using jira rest API to communicat with my jira

```
JiraRestClient client = authentificationInJira();       
Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = " + projectKey);
```

Now i can get issues but my question is how to get creator screen of my issue.

Comment: AFAIK screen is an interface for creating issues. So, you can directly use the end point of Create Issue and create your issue https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Comment: i already seen this ressource but can't find how to get the screen fields ?!?

Comment: I think https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#getting-metadata-for-creating-issues-examples is what you are looking for (createmeta endpoint in JIRA REST API).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment technically screens are just an interface for creating issue. You can use end point of create issue to create an issue via REST API. However, according to [Atlassian Documents](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) following are a sample input:

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "Always do right. This will gratify some people and astonish the REST.",
       "description": "Creating an issue while setting custom field values",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       },       
       "customfield_11050" : "Value that we're putting into a Free Text Field."
   }
}
```

If you need to add input to your custom fields which you normally see in the screens you can use following:

```
 "customfield_10001": {"value": "green", "child": {"value":"blue"} }
```

You can either find your `customefield_ID` from the database or you can find them from the JIRA Administration Panel by clicking on the custom field and grabbing the `ID` from the URL. There is a end point for getting fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Saleh's answer which already contains a link to a helpful page, I would like to mention the `createmeta` endpoint of the JIRA REST API. The purpose of this endpoint is exactly what you need: A description of available and mandatory fields.

Some examples on how to use it can be found on the already linked page: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#getting-metadata-for-creating-issues-examples